# Strange Behavior in Bash For Loop

Tags: bash, shell

Given the following code, BASH's output is unexpected for me and I'm looking for possible solutions (I've tried changing the way I'm quoting but that doesn't seem to affect anything to produce the desired result):

Testing File:

```
            #!/bin/bash
            . FindMissingSettings.function

            Settings[0]="FirstSetting"
            Settings[1]="SecondSetting"
            Settings[2]="ThirdSetting"
            ThisFile="ThisFile"

            find_missing_settings "${Settings[@]}" "$ThisFile"
```

The included FindMissingSettings.function:

```
            #!/bin/bash
            find_missing_settings () {
                Settings=("$@")
                File=$2
                for Setting in "${Settings[@]}"; do
                        echo "$Setting"
                        echo "1"
                    done
                echo "$File"
                echo "2"
            }
```

I expected the output from this script and the included function to be:

```
 FirstSetting
 1
 SecondSetting
 1
 ThirdSetting
 1
 ThisFile
 2
```

However this was the result I received:

```
 FirstSetting
 1
 SecondSetting
 1
 ThirdSetting
 1
 ThisFile
 1
 SecondSetting
 2
```

Why is this and what can I do to provide the desired result?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `find_missing_settings` function, in your variable `Setting`, you have all the given inputs (`FirstSetting`, `Second Setting`, `ThirdSetting`, `ThisFile`). That's why it print it all with during the loop.
Then it print the 2nd setting in the list, so `SecondSetting`

To fix this, you can put `ThisFile` as first parameter of the function:

```
find_missing_settings "$ThisFile" "${Settings[@]}"
```

And change in the `find_missing_settings` function how you get the inputs:

```
    Settings=("${@:2}")
    File=$1
```

The `:2` ask to get the inputs starting from the 2nd one only, and you put the first one (`ThisFile`) in the variable `File`

Comment: Thanks!  I'd like to add that if anyone else is looking to do this and maintain the original command order you can use:  Settings=("${@:1:(${#Settings[@]})}")
 File=("${@:((${#Settings[@]})+1)}")

Comment: @NewStack This only works because you're accessing the original Settings array, so passing it in the first place was pointless. If that's an option, you can dramatically simplify it by just calling `find_missing_settings` without arguments and then using `"${Settings[@]}"` and `$ThisFile` in the function without declaring them.

Comment: Thanks that other guy, I actually realized this last night a short while after posting my comment, decided to use instead `Parameter=("${@}")
 SettingsArray=("${@:1:((${#Parameter[@]})-1)}")
 File=("${@:((${#Parameter[@]}))}")`

Comment: Lol...looking at that snippet of code...BASH certainly is it's own animal.